# prefix not allowed in top level html for amp pages

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, amp-html

When putting prefix for ogp.me in html amp page and validating I get error message prefix not allowed at top level html. What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from the documentation: [AMP HTML Tag Addendum](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-tag-addendum.md)

> AMP HTML allows for most HTML5 standard tags and a few additional tags specific to the AMP runtime. The [AMP Spec](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-format.md) broadly defines the set of tags that are disallowed. AMP Validator implementations, however, must be implemented using a tag whitelist. This addendum lists the set of tags which an AMP Validator should whitelist.
>
> If an HTML tag is not in this list, the AMP Validator does not consider that tag valid in any context. However, many of these tags have additional restrictions. For example **`<script>`** is in the list, but custom javascript is not allowed.

The only solution for this, would be removing the prefix which invalidates the AMP page.